# Using jQuery to set value on SPAN element

Tags: jquery, html, spring

I have an element `<span id="userName.errors" class="errors">Enter Your User Name </span>` i would like to use jquery to remove the text 'Enter Your User Name ' or any element that belongs to the class 'errors'

Comment: Please provide more details, your explanation currently doesn't state the context of your question. Provide some existing code etc

Comment: Using a `.` in an ID is a bad idea. It will require ugly escaping in selectors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `text` method:

```
$(".errors").text("New text here");
```

This targets all elements with the class "errors".

Comment: I think he is better off using .html()